# Laravel JWT dont expires

Tags: php, laravel, token, access-token

Im using firebase/php-jwt this package and try to expire the token after 10 seconds to see if im getting error and its seem like the token is still valid. what im doing wrong?

```
$key = "example_key";
        $token = array(
            "iss" => "http://example.org",
            "aud" => "http://example.com",
            "iat" => 1356999524,
            "nbf" => 10000
        );

        $jwt = JWT::encode($token, $key);
        $decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, $key);

        print_r($decoded);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look here https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-json-web-token-06#section-4.1.5, `nbf` should be a timestamp, if you want it to expire after 10 seconds, you can try setting `exp` at 1356999524 + 10.